# Finding Bugs In NodeJS Website

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, mongoose

I'm coming to the end of the development of my project and am wanting to finalise it by finding any remaining bugs, the problem is I don't want to manually run through my website over and over. I was wondering if its possible to build a script to run through the website over and over and stop whenever it hits a problem.

Is there any kind of application which could do this? I want to test my login script, and signup script on my website.

My website is written in:

NodeJS
Javascript
HTML
Mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) (with PhantomJS) to test your application through UI. Or you can use mocha (Atul answer) for unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mocha test for this.
https://mochajs.org/